# How often should a hermit crab tank be cleaned?

Tags: hermit-crabs, terrariums

I have three pet hermit crabs, and they live in a 10 gallon fish tank. How often should I clean this hermit crab tank? How often should the sand be replaced?

Comment: Every week do a full clean out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally you should spot clean daily (removing uneaten bits of food, etc.).
Deep cleans (taking everything out, rinsing it off, replacing substrate, etc.) should be done about twice a year.

That being said, sometimes your crabs have different ideas. If one or more of them is down for a molt when you want to clean, I wouldn't worry about it too much. Just wait until they're all on the surface again, put them in an iso tank, and do your cleaning then. I've had to go a year+ between deep cleans before due to molting schedules and uncooperative crabs!